# Does a Convex Function need to be Continuous

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

I have been trying the following problem and I am very confused. If possible the problem should be solved with derivatives. If the derivative exists for all the points on the graph then it is continuous.$f'(x_{0}) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0 } \frac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}$ for all $  x_{0}  \in \mathbb{R}$

Question:
Let $V : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Does it have to be continuous? Prove rigorously either way.

Comment: Not every convex function is differentiable. For example, the absolute value function $x\mapsto |x|$ is convex but it has no derivative at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $x\in\mathbb R$, then for all $\lambda \in(0,1)$,
\begin{align*}
V(x)-V(x-1)&\leq {V(x)-V(x-\lambda)\over \lambda}\\
& \leq {V(x+\lambda)-V(x-\lambda)\over 2\lambda}\\
& \leq {V(x+\lambda)-V(x)\over \lambda}\\
&\leq V(x+1)-V(x).
\end{align*}
Thus the difference quotients are bounded.

Comment: By the way, this is not meant to suggest that $V$ is differentiable; boundedness of the difference quotients as $\lambda\to 0$ is sufficient for continuity but not for differentiability.